# mysql php connector not returning last cell value

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = ""
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($row = @mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
        echo "<tr bgcolor='#dcdcdc'>" ;
        echo "<td><a href=\"teststeps.php?id=".$row[0]."\">$row[0] </a></td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[3] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[4] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[5] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[6] . "</td>";
     }
```

when I run the above php code on my local mysql server , my last row value is correctly displayed.

But when the same is deployed on the server and access from client PC , last cell value is empty.

Please help me how to sort this issue out.

Comment: Turn on NOTICE errors to see if it generates some minor error (array index error etc...). And, assuming you are executing `SELECT *` query, make sure deployed and local MySQL servers actually have same number of columns in given table...

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the trailing `</tr>` from your code, that could potentially do it:

```
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "<tr bgcolor='#dcdcdc'>" ;
    echo "<td><a href=\"teststeps.php?id=".$row[0]."\">$row[0] </a></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[3] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[4] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[5] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[6] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
 }
```

Comment: the same code is executing with out any errors on my local machine

Comment: It may depend on your browser whether it corrects the code or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check the database to make sure you have all of the rows in your table.  That would pretty much have to be the problem.

Make sure you have at least 7 columns in there.